# Prefix or Suffix

Tags: magento-1.8

where can I rename Prefix and Suffix **text** in front for my customers...

http://www.andcompany.dk/customer/account/create/

Answer (score 1):

in admin interface go to system->configuration->customers->customer configuration -> tab Name and Address Options. There you can define suffix and prefixes (seperated by ;)

Answer (score 0):

go to Customers->Attrbiutes->Manage Attributes, search for suffix or prefix in grid, click row to edit -> go to tab Manage/Label Options there you can define localization by store

Answer (score 0):

under theme design settings 
system / configuration / design